# What are these small, indoor bugs?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I live in Switzerland and have noticed these small bugs appear in my bedroom, either slowly crawling on the parquet flooring, lazily buzzing around or dead on my windowsill (as pictured):

[image: four dead bugs that need to be identified]

[image]

I'm not sure if these bugs are currently appearing more often – or if I just notice them more because of the fact that I'm spending a lot of time in my bedroom due to Corona lockdown.

The only hint I've got is a friend saying that they live in wooden floors. No idea if that's correct.

Thanks for any help or hints!

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll get a positive ID from that photo. It might be some woodboring beetle, maybe genus *Anobium* or *Hedobia*. FTR, if they are chewing on your wooden floors, you might be able to hear them if you listen carefully.

I suggest you collect some, maybe even living, in a small tube and ask a specialist. My first idea would be someone at a nearby university or natural history museum working in entomology, and specifically on Coleoptera if possible.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a species of Varied Carpet Beetles. The varied carpet beetle (Anthrenus verbasci) is a 3 mm-long beetle belonging to the family Dermestidae. They are a common species, often considered a pest of domestic houses and, particularly, natural history museums, where the larvae may damage natural fibers and can damage carpets, furniture, clothing, and insect collections.

Source: [Varied Carpet Beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varied_carpet_beetle)

Comment: This is incorrect

Comment: This is what I could find closest to those shown in the image. I might be wrong.